# Can i import users from LDAP to Keycloak only the first time they logged in to Keycloak?

Tags: ldap, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

In the Keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#synchronizing-ldap-users-to-keycloak), under Synchronizing LDAP users to Keycloak, it says:

> If you set the Import Users option, the LDAP Provider handles
> importing LDAP users into the Keycloak local database. The first time
> a user logs in, the LDAP provider imports the LDAP user into the
> Keycloak database and validates the LDAP password. **This first time a
> user logs in is the only time Keycloak imports the user**. If you click
> the Users menu in the Admin Console and click the View all users
> button, **you only see the LDAP users authenticated at least once by
> Keycloak**. **Keycloak imports users this way, so this operation does not
> trigger an import of the entire LDAP user database**.

But.. actually, I get the exact opposite behavior. When I add LDAP configuration to Keycloak (v.20), it immediately syncs all the LDAP users to my Keycloak users list. How can I import just the users only on the first time a user logs in, as the documentation states.

the configuration I use:

```
{
  providerId: 'ldap',
  providerType: 'org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProvider',
  name: 'ldap',
  config: {
    enabled: ['true'],
    connectionUrl: [''],
    bindDn: [''],
    bindCredential: [''],
    startTls: ['false'],
    useTruststoreSpi: ['ldapsOnly'],
    connectionPooling: ['false'],
    authType: ['simple'],
    allowKerberosAuthentication: ['false'],
    useKerberosForPasswordAuthentication: ['false'],
    cachePolicy: ['DEFAULT'],
    connectionTimeout: [''],
    usersDn: [''],
    usernameLDAPAttribute: ['sAMAccountName'],
    rdnLDAPAttribute: ['cn'],
    uuidLDAPAttribute: ['objectGUID'],
    userObjectClasses: ['person, organizationalPerson, user'],
    customUserSearchFilter: [''],
    readTimeout: [''],
    batchSizeForSync: [''],
    vendor: ['ad'],
    editMode: ['READ_ONLY'],
    searchScope: [''],
    pagination: ['false'],
    importEnabled: ['true'],
    syncRegistrations: ['false'],
    usePasswordModifyExtendedOp: ['false'],
    validatePasswordPolicy: ['false'],
    trustEmail: ['false'],
    changedSyncPeriod: ['-1'],
    fullSyncPeriod: ['-1'],
  },
```